Identifying different firearms residues
Can forensics differentiate between gunshot residue from a handgun and that from a shotgun when it is on a suspect’s hands?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If a suspect was found to have gunshot residue on his hands, could he show that he had been on a legitimate activity involving shotguns, I.e., game shooting, as a defence against an accusation of murder with a handgun?

No worldbuilding context present. Why not look at some real-life forensics cases. I suspect you'll find that the shape of the guns makes a difference to the way any hot-gas escaping might touch flesh. Then there's black-powder Vs nitrocellulose. Worth looking into the properties of those and where they're used (or when in history).

Welcome to Worldbuilding! We try not to answer questions about current science and existing technology. Those questions are better asked elsewhere (try Chemistry SE or, IIRC, Forensic SE). We are here for the edges of science and best guesses at unknowns.

The location of the gunpowder residue would be very different between firing a pistol and firing a shotgun, at least when using the normal firing procedures.
A pistol is fired with arms extended, far from one's face, and either held with overlapping hands, or else held with one hand and the other hand far from it; a shotgun is normally fired in an entirely different position, with the gun propped on the shoulder and the shooter looking down the sights, leaving residue on the face, and asymmetric residue on the left and right hands and arms.
From what I have seen in movies, the forensic report includes a diagram of where the residue was found.

"At least when using normal firing procedures" - any defense lawyer is going to have a field day with that

You may be thinking of victim residue charts, for the shooter they ussually just test the hands and smpling is not precise enough to give any kind of image, it is more yes/no than anything else.

Possibly
So, there are different smokeless powder compositions depending on primarily whether you are shooting rifle or Pistol.
Famously YouTuber Kentucky Ballistics had a near-fatal accident with some .50 BMG SLAPP rounds that had been inadvertently loaded with Pistol powder.
The difference is that Pistol powder burns quicker and generates peak pressure much quicker (as this needs to happen over the 6 or so inches of Pistol barrel length) whereas Rifle powder burns slower and generates a lower peak pressure, but for longer (e.g. over a standard 20 inch barrel length)
however - Shotgun powder tends to be Pistol powder - as the projectiles are smaller and lighter.
I am not well-versed enough in chemical forensics to know if a test could distinguish from residue between the different types of powder.
But let's assume they can - in most countries where owning a Shotgun is legal, owning a Bolt-Action rifle is legal - so for the purposes of your story, change from using a Shotgun to a rifle for game hunting - and you've got a plausible explanation.
However if you want even more reasonable doubt however, have your protagonist use a Pistol Calibre rifle (.22lr, 9mm, .45 ACP) - or a Lever-Action rifle (.357 magnum or .44 magnum)

Maybe. It depends on the precise chemistry of the powders and primers used in the relevant cartridges. If someone had planned to confuse the issue and obtained or custom-loaded cartridges for the two kinds of guns that used the same chemistry, it would be impractical to distinguish them.
